# Read a text file line-by-line into a string with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have made a keylogger with python that encrypts and saves keylogs as numbers to a textfile (data.txt). I also wanted it to send the encrypted keylogs (numbers) to my gmail account using smtplib. **the problem is that i get this output:**

```
5
5
6
5
6
2
1
0
4
4
4
7
5
9
5
\
,
4
2
3
8
6
9
1
0
1
5
3
7
2
5
6
\
```

Instead of this:

```
123456789108765
682371638321237
```

**I have been using this code to get all text from the textfile as a list:**

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
                x=(f.readlines())
```

**And this code to get all items from that list and print them line by line:**

```
x = '\n'.join(map(str, x))
        print(str(x))
        message = str(x) # this message gets sent to my gmail account
```

If you feel that this question is misssing some information that you may need to answer my question then i would be glad to include that information in my question!

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to replace:

```
x = '\n'.join(map(str, x))
```

with:

```
x = ' '.join(map(str, x))   # results in `1 2 3 4 5` etc
```

or remove the space completely, if you want your numbers like this `123456789`